# Flat fee time tracking software for 250 employees

Tags: time-management, saas

I am looking for a flat fee (no per user pricing) SaaS time tracking tool for employees. The current team size is around 250 people.

The tool has to have:

- Time tracker
- Time reports (including sharing via link and export to PDF and Excel)
- Unlimited number of projects and clients
- Mobile app
- Slack chatbot
- GDPR ready

So far I found only two of them - [Quidlo Timesheets](https://www.quidlo.com/timesheets/pricing) and [Minutedock](https://minutedock.com/pricing) (Minutedock is not 100% flat fee). I know Clockify had a flat fee pricing plan but they started charging per user.

Do you know any other time tracking tools with monthly flat payments?

Comment: Hi. I know you want SaaS, but any chance of you self-hosting or getting someone to host for you? If so, I can make a recommendation. Also what is price limit per month?

Comment: Hi @ZZ, I would prefer to have it hosted as a SaaS. I don't want to deal with it as it is an additional cost (not only the server but people taking care of it). There are some project management tools like Basecamp that charge flat fee but somehow time trackers, although they use less resources, they charge per-user fee. I see Quidlo charges 39 USD/month, so I would say, I could pay up to 59 USD / month (around 700 USD/year) for all 250 users.